# Алгоритм поискм маршрута

Tags: алгоритм, маршрут

Есть примерно 200 маршрутов в JSON в виде последовательности номеров остановок {1,2,3,4,5}, {3,4,5,6,7,8}, ... Есть таблица дополнительных пересечений маршрутов в виде: {4,17,18} - эти остановки рядом и могут быть пересадки. Каким алгоритмом лучше всего строить маршруты из точки А в точку Б - интересуют 5 наиболее оптимальных. Примером схематичного отображения может быть карта метро Москвы! Если рекурсивно перебирать все варианты, некоторые маршруты строит по 15 минут...

Comment: Волновой алгоритм на матрице связности.

Comment: что такое "оптимальный" маршрут? Какие критерии оптимальности? Вы все пробовали из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8) - см раздел "Алгоритмы"?